# Tinymce validate editor data in django

Tags: html, django, security, tinymce

I am using tinymce as an editor for a blog in django. The output that i get is pure html that i extract from the DOM of the editor. The same is stored in database and rendered when a person visits the page.

This method although simple but can cause injection of script tags into the same. What i want to know is how can i prevent them so that the data that i save is valid from the editor and has not been tampered with. Code for timymce is

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'div.editor',
  theme: 'inlite',
  plugins: 'image table link paste contextmenu textpattern autolink',
  insert_toolbar: 'quickimage quicktable',
  selection_toolbar: 'bold italic | quicklink h2 h3 blockquote',
  inline: true,
  paste_data_images: true,
  content_css: [
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
});
```

and while submitting the form i simply post the contents under div.editor .Is this the right way to go or is there some other method. Also how can i be sure from the point of security that the data does not contain script or any other kind of tracking data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `valid_elements` / `extended_valid_elements` configuration options in TinyMCE to control what tags you want to allow.  This will help you with ensuring that TinyMCE only allows tags you want.

That being said, **you can never assume client side validation is enough to ensure your application is safe from  invalid HTML, injection attacks, XSS, etc.**

The reality is I can post data to the app using other tools (CURL etc) so that I don't really go through your UI.  If you misconfigure TinyMCE you might allow tags without realizing you have done so.  You should always validate data server-side before storing it into your database - this is the only way to ensure that what you are saving is "safe".

Comment: That is exactly what i want to know, How to perform validation server side ? Is there any app in django that i can use for the same. Alternatively i recently stumbled on setting content of editor. Would that remove script tags ?

Comment: If you want help with server-side validation in Django I would create a question where the title and tags point to that specifically.  Configuring TinyMCE's `valid_elements` will limit what TinyMCE will accept but as stated above that is assuming that someone is not trying to be deceptive.